# How do I write “live for yourself” in Chinese?

Tags: translation

I’m looking to get a tattoo of this phrase which basically means live your life to make yourself happy and not others in Chinese writing but I don’t want to use translator sites because tend to translate wrongly a lot

Comment: There's nothing wrong with Google Translate's result “为自己而活”

Comment: Quote:- "...live your life to make yourself happy and not others....?" 自私而活

Answer (score 6):

hipster: 做自己

artistic person: 为自己而活

cool boss: 人不为己 天诛地灭

the rebellious protagonist in fantasy fiction: 我命由我不由天

Sexually Suggestive Puns: 做爱做的事

motivated person: 活出自己

grandma: 善待自己

Answer (score 0):

Well, depends what you mean.

If you mean, be totally selfish and disregard others, live for yourself, as American google says, 为自己而活。

But Shakespeare wrote, “No man is an island."

没有人是孤立的

Maybe you mean: 做你自己 be yourself

Unto thine own self be true.

Answer (score 0):

Just Want to add two extra options for your reference.

活出自我

坚持自我

自我 sounds better than 自己.

Hope this can help.